# Copy animated viewport color to another object

Tags: animation, keyframes, color

I have animated (set keyframes) for the viewport color of an object (cube). Now I would like to copy the animation / keyframes of the color channels to another object (cube.001). But I don`t want to copy other channels (like transform,...). How to do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by either copying the keyframes themselves or by sharing Action data in an NLA strip. Using NLAs means that changes made to the shared Action on one object will also be reflected in the behaviour of the other object.

---

**Method 1, Duplicate Keyframes:**

1. Select only the Viewport Color keyframes from your source object in the Dope Sheet.
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to "Copy".
   [image]
   Notice that the Transform keyframes/channels are not selected.
3. Add a single dummy keyframe to Viewport Color on your destination object.
4. Select only the Viewport Color keyframes from your destination object in the Dope Sheet.
5. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to "Copy".
   [image]
6. Delete the dummy keyframes if they're still there.

**Method 2, Shared Actions:**

- Place the keyframes for Viewport Color specially in their own Action datablock, and then push that Action onto an NLA track for both of the objects:
  [image]
- You can now add another NLA track or active action to keyframe the other properties of either object.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!! Method 1 works. Previously, I tried copy paste without adding a color keyframe first (your step 3). Then the color values (RGB 0-1) were actually written into the existing transform values (xyz) (felt like a bug somehow). Any suggestion how I can make this process efficient for 20+ objects without manually adding keyframes etc? I haven`t tried method 2, as I am not familiar with the NLA, but will do so soon.

Comment: @ChrisM It seems like if you select all the objects, you can copy and paste just once on the Dope Sheet to get all of them, but I think you still need the dummy keyframes/channels. If any of those objects don't have other keyframes yet, you could [CTRL]+[L] to link "Animation Data" and then maybe "Make Single User > Animation Data" to dissociate them. I'd recommend the NLA method, unless you want to later manually update all 20+ of the objects.